# What alternative techniques are available to perform variable selection with big data?

Tags: time-series, pca, model-selection, predictor

I have a 88x6500 dataset of people income, where 88 are time periods (quarters) and 6500 are people. My independent variable is X = income and my dependent variable is Y = average houses price in a country. I am studying how the income of the richest people of a country affects its average houses prices.

I would like to perform variable selection and filter/select the richest people in my dataset: my intention is to employ principal components analysis, but since I am not a statistician I have some questions:

1. Is there any specific rule (even of thumb) to pick the number of principal components? i.e. if I know that the first 1000 < p regressors can explain about 90% of variance but the first 1100 < p can explain about 95% of variance, how can I decide how many regressors exclude in the final linear regression model? (of course logically there is a trade-off between model simplicity and explanatory power);
2. Are there any other similar or more accurate techniques to perform variable selection? It should be similar to the logic of PCA and other than ridge, lasso, elastic net regression or best subset selection;
3. Does it make sense in this case to make a supervised principal component analysis including the dependent variable in this case?
4. Since I have many missing values, excluding people with more than 10 yrs of missing values and using missing imputation techniques (such as linear interpolation or with a constant) for other people could invalidate the results?
5. Is there any computational problem with a so huge dataset (I am working with MATLAB and R)? In particular regarding the number of predictors being extremely higher than the time series dimension.
6. Since the unit of measurement of the income is the same across the dataset (thousand of dollars for people income people and for the average house prices) and since I am focused on the richest people in the sample (so demeaning maybe does not make much sense), can I skip data standardization without any complications in interpreting the results?

Comment: Not sure this is what one could call "big data" .. If I understand well, you have only one explanatory variable, which is average houses prices ? So I don't see why you want to perform "selection" variable ? Or do you have other (many others) explanatory variables ?

Comment: No, average houses prices is my explained variable (of size  88x1). My explanatory variables (of size 88x6500) are people income, i.e. the first explanatory variable (first column 88x1) is the income of the first person from quarter 1 to quarter 88, the second explanatory variable (second column 88x1) is the income of the second person from quarter 1 to quarter 88 and so on...

Comment: Ok, if so, i think you just have one explanatory variable with repeated measurments .. and i think you should rather use methods for longitidinal data ..

Comment: and I wonder .. you just have the average houses prices for the whole period ?

Comment: The hypothesis I want to test is if people with the biggest income can explain variations in average houses prices. For example, let's consider 10 people with the biggest income: regressing the average houses prices on a 88x10 matrix (where the columns are income of the richest people) gives a high R squared (say 35%).

Comment: the period you are working on lasts 22 years .. do you adjust your data for inflation ? and how is calculated the "average" houses prices ?

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington what do you mean? The explained variable is a time series of the average houses prices at time t. So element 1 of the column vector of the explained variable is the average (of the country) houses prices in quarter 1, element 2 of the column vector of the explained variable is the average (of the country) houses prices in quarter 2, and so on

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington yes I did take into account inflation. Average is cross-sectional mean of house prices at quarter t in that specific country.

Comment: ok ! it's more clear now

Comment: and as I understand it now, you still have only one explantory variables, and I suppose that you should use times series modelisations .. what did you do when you get 35% ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134556/discussion-between-barbab-and-mrsmithgoestowashington).